# Python 2.7, not Anaconda 3 running when I run as root using sudo

Tags: python, linux

When I run python on RHEL, I automatically use Anaconda3:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

When I sudo python, it defaults to python 2.7.

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 12 2018, 05:31:16)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

"which python" vs "sudo which python" gives:

```
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python

/bin/python
```

How can I make sudo commands run Anaconda distribution of python.  Is there any risk of changing this?

Can I make the change permanently, or do I just run python from sudo using the full Anaconda path?

Comment: have you tried `conda python` ?

Comment: sudo cant find conda, not in its path

Comment: sudo /opt/anaconda3/bin/python works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Python3.5.2 as default Python version on CentOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45542690/608639); and others like [Unable to set default python version to python3 in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41986507/608639), [How to update-alternatives to Python 3 without breaking apt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43062608/608639), etc.

Comment: This is more of an issue with different python environments being defaulted under root sudo access, than via normal account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your python version and installation location for root is different. If you want to use `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python` , there are different ways:
You can add `alias python="/opt/anaconda3/bin/python" to your .bashrc`file of root user and re login or source this `.bashrc`.

Other way is to use `#!/opt/anaconda3/bin/python` in your python code when you run it from root user so that is uses your anaconda distribution.

Point is, you have to use `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python` as your python binary.

You mayalso remove `python2.7` from your root user and add `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python` in your `PATH` env variable.

Also, you can add `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python` in your PATH environment variable and use python3 instead of python from root user. or you can use  `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python` instead of `python`

**Make sure the permissions and owner ship of paths are good without conflicts among users.**