# How to revert overriden python2 to python3 in Linux?

Tags: python, linux

I accidentally overridden `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/python2` to `/usr/bin/python3.8` and now I'm not able to reinstall and install anything because I get this error when using apt
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'`.

I tried to reinstall `python-minimal`, `python2.7` but without success.

I also tried to remove the `python2.7` but I can't do that either because it depends on `libgda` which I cannot install either because my system does not recognize `Python2.7`.

Any idea how can I restore the old version of Python?

Comment: Did you try simply running `apt install python2.7`? A `ModuleNotFoundError` is inside of python itself, that's not part of installing python

Comment: `python2.7` is already installed but I cannot find any executable file that I would copy to `/usr/bin`.. Every python file in `/usr/bin` starts `python3.8`

Comment: **Do not uninstall Python 2.7!** Many system tools rely on it and you might damage your system beyond repair.

Comment: Let me describe my process :D 
1. Uninstall `python2.7` - denied, unmet dependency `libgda-5.0-common` which depends on `libjs-jquery`
2. Tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install` - denied, `Errors where encountered while processing: python-minimal`
3. Tried to reinstall `python-minimal` - Denied again because of `libgda` dependency

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update-alternatives to Python 3 without breaking apt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062608/how-to-update-alternatives-to-python-3-without-breaking-apt)

Comment: @KlausD. Yea well, I can't do it anyway, but thank you for the warning, I won't try it again

Comment: @KlausD. Not really, I can't even find a single file that would run Python2.7

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218911/17609

Comment: @moooeeeep Whoa, copy `python2.7` from Live CD actually worked, many thanks. Could you paste it as a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just messed up with the symlinks (`/usr/bin/python2` and `/usr/bin/python`) and the actual executable is still in place, you might be able to fix the problem by restoring the links:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2 
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Otherwise you can try to download a live-ubuntu and just copy the Python executable from the live OS back in place to fix your broken installation.

Answer (score 0):

follow this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911448/uninstall-python-3-6) to uninstall the python.

then make a fresh installment of python 2.7